# Is it possible alter build in excel find replace dialog box using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there is any way to alter build in excel find replace dialog box using vba? for example i want to disable the "within": workbook criteria.

i expected an output that excel find replace work only within sheet not within workbook

Comment: You can make a custom userform, but you can't easily alter the built-in dialogs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the advanced options for find and replace, you can specify workbook or worksheet - what did you want to alter?

Comment: i want to alter that show only worksheet in advanced option

Comment: Showing care for your question's formatting would improve its chances to be considered by others. Capitalizing correctly is not that difficult in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom form which looks like Find/Replace dialog, but without the dropdown that you want to disable. Then you can write a simple sub to display the form when user presses Ctrl+F:

```
Public Sub ShowFindDialog
    MyFindDialog.Show
End Sub
```

To assign it to Ctrl+f key, go to Developer -> Macros -> find your macro and click "Options..." -> specify "Ctrl+f" as the shortcut key.

Now the users can still access built-in Find/Replace dialog through ribbon. To remove it, right click on the ribbon and select "Customize The Ribbon...". On the right hand side of the window expand the "Home" tab, right-click on "Editing" group and select "Remove".

**EDIT:** The last bit about customizing Ribbon will only work on your computer and will apply to all workbooks. If you want to apply these settings for a particular workbook, it get's more difficult. You can look, for example, [here](https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/customise-ribbon-excel-workbook/).

**EDIT2:** Instead of building a custom form, you can use `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show`. To do it just for one sheet, add the following macro and assign it to Ctrl+F as I explained earlier:

```
Public Sub ShowFindDialog()
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "MySheet" Then
        'ON MySheet show find dialog without an option to search within workbook
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show
    Else
        'For all other sheets show regular find dialog
        Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Find...").Execute
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel build in find and replace dialog box has contain some parameter like  search,Look in,Match Case...etc .i want to only work find or replace   "within :worksheet"  on sheet 1. "within :workbook" is disable in sheet 1,but it enable other sheet